# servo.read() starts at negative value, no matter where servo actually is

Tags: arduino-mega, servo

I don't like how my servo quickly jumps to the default middle position, so I commented out the line where `DEFAULT_PULSE_WIDTH` is set in `Servo.cpp`:

```
//servos[this->servoIndex].ticks = usToTicks(DEFAULT_PULSE_WIDTH);
```

Unfortunately while this stopped the servo from moving on execution of `attach`, the position of the servo is now showing up as `-52`!

Just running the following in `setup()` is enough to generate the bug:

```
int servo_pin = 53;
servo.attach(servo_pin);
Serial.print("Initial position: ");
Serial.println(servo.read());  //returns -52
```

This last line returns `-52` no matter what position the servo is actually in, which has bad consequences (its initial movement is way off).

Note I get the same behavior when I set the `DEFAULT_PULSE_WIDTH` to `0` in `Servo.h`.

I am using a Mega -- an Elegoo clone -- on Windows 10.

Note I got the ideas for stopping the servo from moving on initialization from these threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892922/how-to-stop-an-arduino-servo-from-moving-during-the-myservo-attach-command?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695670/attach-arduino-servo-without-moving

Comment: you are using Windows 10 to control the servo somehow?

Comment: Yes, mentioned at the end of my question.

Comment: how are you using Windows to to control the servo?

Comment: I'm using the IDE in windows just using a standard sweep algorithm. You can see code here: https://onlinegdb.com/HJIKaZv9z  But really all you need to reproduce it is what I showed above in `setup()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be starting from a fundamental misunderstanding of RC hobby type PWM servos.  To put it simply, they do not electronically output any position information.

Until you have commanded a position and the servo loop has had a fair chance to seek to that, the position of the servo is utterly and entirely unknowable.

This is stated in the documentation of the Arduino servo system:

```
read()

Description

Read the current angle of the servo (the value passed to the last call to write()).
```

As this explains, the returned value is not the *physical* position, but rather the last *commanded* position.

Until you have commanded a position (something your code does not do) the return value of this call is physically meaningless.

Comment: For those curious, what you would need is a servo with feedback. Something like this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1404  I thought I was accessing that information, but no.